# How to get process information from windowHandle in Native with Java?

Tags: java, process, native

I have windowHandle of a window. I need to get other information about the process like CPU%, memory name etc.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering use [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). Download jna.jar and platform.jar from [here](https://java.net/projects/jna/downloads/directory/3.2.7).

You may have noticed that we can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **user32.dll** to get the pid from a window handle. Then we can use [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **kernel32.dll** to get a pointer to that process. Then [the bunch of APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetModuleBaseName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **psapi.dll** can help you to get process information from that process object and the [GetProcessTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in **kernel32.dll** can return cpu usage. The `GetProcessMemoryInfo` contains a structure named [PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  which needs [Structure in JNA](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html) to handle.

```
static class Kernel32 {
    static { Native.register("kernel32"); }
    public static int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
    public static int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;
    public static native int GetLastError();
    public static native Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, Pointer pointer);
    public static native boolean GetProcessTimes(Pointer hProcess, int lpCreationTime,int LPFILETIME lpExitTime, int lpKernelTime, int lpUserTime
}

static class Psapi {
    static { Native.register("psapi"); }
    public static native int GetModuleBaseNameW(Pointer hProcess, Pointer hmodule, char[] lpBaseName, int size);
    ...
}

static class User32DLL {
    static { Native.register("user32"); }
    public static native int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hWnd, PointerByReference pref);
    public static native int GetWindowTextW(HWND hWnd, char[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
}

PointerByReference pointer = new PointerByReference();
GetWindowThreadProcessId(yourHandle, pointer);
Pointer process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pointer.getValue());
GetModuleBaseNameW(process, null, buffer, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);
System.out.println("Active window process: " + Native.toString(buffer));
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that after 2 hours of searching, this was the only answer that actually worked for me in terms of being able to list both title and process in one go! Thank you!!!